How to join two tables in MySQL using specific columns?

I want to write a query to get the customer name and product name order by first name.
I have two tables in my MySQL database, let's call them customer details table and product detail table. Each table has several columns, but I only want to join them based on specific columns. For example, let's say I want to join customer details table.first_name with product detail table.product_name.
Could someone please provide me with the correct MySQL query syntax to achieve this? Also, if there are any performance considerations or best practices I should be aware of when joining tables in this manner, I would appreciate any insights.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

You will join rows (customer_details_table rows with product_detail_table rows). You won't base the join on first_name and product_name (a customer that happens to have the same name as a product?), but on the column(s) that relate the two tables.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. While it is a good idea to show the tables, you should use formatted text instead of images.

Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE customer_details_table; and B) product_detail_table; C) your query attempt; for analysis.

As your image, it has customer_id in both tables which we can use for joining.
Or you can join with any column name with following syntax.
But Joining using "strings" might be caused to following issues

Performance Overhead
Inflexibility
Difficulty in Index Usage
Resource Consumption

To avoid these issues, it's generally recommended to join using "int"
SELECT
  `c`.`first_name`,
  `p`.`product_name`
FROM `customer_details` AS `c`
JOIN `product_details` AS `p` ON `c`.`customer_id` = `p`.`customer_id`
ORDER BY
`c`.`first_name`;

MySQL Joins By w3schools

I disagree with all those negatives about "joining using strings".

When you join with a "string" instead of "int", you'll definitely feel the delay of the execution. so That's proven No 1.

I'd be interested to see a test case and a benchmark.
